# Why I'm not able to clear my setInterval?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, setinterval, use-effect

I'm trying to create an **automatic counter** when the component(Home here for instance) renders in the view. The counter should start at 1 and stop at 10. But I'm not able to clear my setInterval at 10. The counter remains incrementing.
What is the problem?

Thanks a lot.

```
export const Home = () => {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1)
    let timer = useRef()


    const animate = () => {
        if(counter === 10){
          clearInterval(timer.current)
        }else{
          setCounter((previous) => previous + 1) 
        }
    }


    useEffect(() => {
        timer.current = window.setInterval(() => {
            animate()
        }, 900)
    
     }, [])



  return (
      <div style={{textAlign: "center"}}>
         <h1>{counter}</h1>
      </div>
  )
}
```

Comment: Where is `useRef()`? I think that needs to be `useEffect()`.

Comment: Because from the `animate` perspective `counter` is always 1.

Comment: And instead of having the timer's callback function be an anonymous wrapper around `animate()` which is called with no arguments, just have the timer's callback be `animate` (no parenthesis).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem is the closure of `animate` function over the initial value of `counter`, i.e. 1. As a result, the condition `counter === 10` never evaluates to true.

This is why you should never lie about the dependencies of the `useEffect` hook. Doing so can lead you to bugs because of closures over the stale values from the previous renders of your component.

#### Solution

You can get rid of `animate()` function and write the logic inside the `useEffect` hook.

```js
function App() {
  const [counter, setCounter] = React.useState(1);
  const counterRef = React.useRef(counter);

  React.useEffect(() => {
    const id = setInterval(() => {
      // if "counter" is 10, stop the interval
      if (counterRef.current === 10) {
        clearInterval(id);
      } else {
        // update the "counter" and "counterRef"
        setCounter((prevCounter) => {
          counterRef.current = ++prevCounter;
          return prevCounter;
        });
      }
    }, 900);

    // clearn interval on unmount
    return () => clearInterval(id);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById("root"));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd create a second `useEffect()` for clearing the interval:

```js
const { useEffect, useRef, useState } = React;

const Home = () => {
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState(1);
  const timer = useRef();

  useEffect(() => {
    timer.current = setInterval(() => {
      setCounter(x => x + 1);
    }, 900);

    // in case the component unmounts before the timer finishes
    return () => clearInterval(timer.current);
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter === 10) {
      clearInterval(timer.current);
    }
  }, [counter]);

  return (
    <div style={{ textAlign: 'center' }}>
      <h1>{counter}</h1>
    </div>
  );
}

ReactDOM.render(<Home/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/17.0.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/17.0.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because modifying `ref.current` doesn't trigger a rerender.
You need to use `useEffect` to clear it.

```js
 const animate = () => {
    setCounter((previous) => previous + 1);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (counter === 10) clearInterval(timer.current);
  }, [counter]);
```